# using a macro in all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am new at VBA and managed to put together a userform that works, it is a simple one to enter call details, one at the time.

My workbook has several sheets, "July 18 calls", "August 18 calls", etc.  The problem is that the code only works for the "July 18 calls" sheet.

if I change to another month, it gives me a "subscript out of range" error.

All I want to do is use the macro this month, then for August, etc.

The code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("July 18 calls")
 
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With ws
    If Me.txtDateBox.Value = "" Then...AND MORE CODE...
```

I cannot get my head around the code to make it work in any active worksheet but I would settle for something simpler even if I have to change the name of the sheet once a month!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try replacing:

```
Set ws = Sheets("July 18 calls")
```

with:

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

and to make the worksheet selection automatic, use:

```
Set ws = Sheets(Format(Date, "mmmm yy") & " calls")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that worked.  Also, it was giving an error as the label for August had an extra space!

Comment: @aureli  You will find that using macros will help you cleanup the worksheet.